# ÚLTIMA FECHA EN REGISTROS DUPLICADOS EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con 2 tablas en **sql server**, `SEG_PORT_OUT_MAR23` y `TB_SURVIVAL_PRE_2023_v3`.

Necesito hacer el siguiente update para que actualice los datos en la de `SEG_PORT_OUT_MAR23`, pero en la otra tabla tengo registros con el mismo `mdn_definitivo`. Lo que necesito es, que tome el registro con la fecha más reciente.

[image: Este es un ejemplo de los 2 registros con el mismo mdn y diferente fecha]

```
UPDATE TA 
    SET TA.AGRUPACION_CANAL=TB.AGRUPACION_CANAL
      , TA.MASTER_PDV=TB.MASTER_PDV
      , TA.CANAL_VTA=TB.CANAL_VTA
      , TA.CVE_PDV=TB.CLAVE_PDV
      , TA.FECHA_ACTIVACION=TB.FECHA_ACTIVACION
      , TA.ID_CONTRATO=CASE WHEN (TB.CONTRATO IS NOT NULL OR TB.CONTRATO<>'0') AND (FUENTE_PORTABILIDAD='LEGACY' OR  FUENTE_PORTABILIDAD IS NULL) 
            THEN TB.CONTRATO
            ELSE TA.ID_CONTRATO 
        END
     , TA.REGION=TB.REGION
     , TA.SUBREGION=TB.SUBREGION
     , TA.FUENTE_ID='TRANSACCIONES MES POR MDN EFECTIVO 2023'
     , TA.PC_CVE_VENDEDOR=TB.CVE_UNICA_EJECUTIVO
     , TA.MERCADO=TB.MERCADO
     , TA.VENDEDOR=TB.NOMBRE_EJECUTIVO_UNICO
     , TA.ICCID=CASE WHEN TA.ICCID IS NULL 
                    THEN TB.SIM 
                ELSE TA.ICCID END
     , TA.MODALIDAD='PREPAGO'
     , TA.MDN_INICIAL=TB.MDN_INICIAL 
     , TA.TIPO_VENTA=TB.TIPO_VENTA
     , TA.SIM_BENEFICIOS=TB.SIM_BENEFICIOS
     , TA.MODELO_EQUIPO=TB.MODELO_EQUIPO
     , TA.PROPIEDAD=TB.PROPIEDAD
     , TA.PLAN_TARIFARIO_HOMO=TB.PLAN_TARIFARIO_HOMO
     , TA.FECHA_PORT_IN=TB.FECHA_PORT_IN
     , TA.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO=TB.FECHA_INAR 
        FROM ICATT.DBO.SEG_PORT_OUT_MAR23 TA 
            INNER JOIN Consumos.dbo.TB_SURVIVAL_PRE_2023_v3 TB
            ON TA.MDN_PORTADO=TB.MDN_DEFINITIVO AND TA.MASTER_PDV IS NULL AND TB.EFECTIVO='SI'
```

Comment: Trate de usar  la función MAX(FECHA_ACTIVACION) pero no funciona.

Comment: Haz de cuenta que no sabemos nada de las tablas que estás usando, de qué motor de base de datos usas ni la versión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A priori, una posible solución podría ser utilizar el operador apply.

```
UPDATE TA 
    SET TA.AGRUPACION_CANAL=TB.AGRUPACION_CANAL
      , TA.MASTER_PDV=TB.MASTER_PDV
      , TA.CANAL_VTA=TB.CANAL_VTA
      , TA.CVE_PDV=TB.CLAVE_PDV
      , TA.FECHA_ACTIVACION=TB.FECHA_ACTIVACION
      , TA.ID_CONTRATO=CASE WHEN (TB.CONTRATO IS NOT NULL OR TB.CONTRATO<>'0') 
                            AND (
                                FUENTE_PORTABILIDAD='LEGACY' 
                                OR  FUENTE_PORTABILIDAD IS NULL
                                ) 
            THEN TB.CONTRATO
            ELSE TA.ID_CONTRATO 
        END
     , TA.REGION=TB.REGION
     , TA.SUBREGION=TB.SUBREGION
     , TA.FUENTE_ID='TRANSACCIONES MES POR MDN EFECTIVO 2023'
     , TA.PC_CVE_VENDEDOR=TB.CVE_UNICA_EJECUTIVO
     , TA.MERCADO=TB.MERCADO
     , TA.VENDEDOR=TB.NOMBRE_EJECUTIVO_UNICO
     , TA.ICCID=CASE WHEN TA.ICCID IS NULL 
                    THEN TB.SIM 
                ELSE TA.ICCID END
     , TA.MODALIDAD='PREPAGO'
     , TA.MDN_INICIAL=TB.MDN_INICIAL 
     , TA.TIPO_VENTA=TB.TIPO_VENTA
     , TA.SIM_BENEFICIOS=TB.SIM_BENEFICIOS
     , TA.MODELO_EQUIPO=TB.MODELO_EQUIPO
     , TA.PROPIEDAD=TB.PROPIEDAD
     , TA.PLAN_TARIFARIO_HOMO=TB.PLAN_TARIFARIO_HOMO
     , TA.FECHA_PORT_IN=TB.FECHA_PORT_IN
     , TA.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO=TB.FECHA_INAR 
        FROM ICATT.DBO.SEG_PORT_OUT_MAR23 TA
            cross apply (
                Select top(1) * From
                Consumos.dbo.TB_SURVIVAL_PRE_2023_v3 X
                WHERE X.MDN_DEFINITIVO = TA.MDN_PORTADO
                AND X.EFECTIVO='SI'
                ORDER BY FECHA_ACTIVACION DESC
            ) TB
            WHERE 
                 TA.MASTER_PDV IS NULL;
```

El mismo, recupera en el subconjunto TB el primer registro (depende del order by), que encaje con lo filtrado, y donde la tabla `Consumos.dbo.TB_SURVIVAL_PRE_2023_v3` llamada X, se iguale con lo que tiene el conjunto exterior para `TA.MDN_PORTADO`

Como no has puesto un escenario mejor, es lo más que me puedo acercar con la respuesta.

Te recomiendo, que antes de aplicar la update, te asegures que realiza explicitamente lo que requieres.

[Operador apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)